# How can I reference a div with a dynamically generated id from code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to reference a div with a dynamically generated ID and with what I have tried so far I am receiving a null reference exception.

The div in question

```
<div id="div<%# Eval("Agreement") %>" class="childGrid" style="display:none;position:relative;left:25px;">
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvHistoricalRenewals" OnRowCommand="gvHistoricalRenewals_RowCommand"
                                OnRowDataBound="gvHistoricalRenewals_RowDataBound" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                DataKeyNames="BatchNum" EmptyDataText="No agreements found" Width="80%" CellPadding="4"
                                ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Both">
                                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Maroon" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
                                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:ButtonField DataTextField="Agreement" CommandName="Agreement" HeaderText="Agreement" SortExpression="Agreement" meta:resourceKey="lblAgreement" ControlStyle-ForeColor="#822402" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CoverageDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" HeaderText="Coverage Date" SortExpression="CoverageDate" meta:resourceKey="lblCoverageDate" ReadOnly="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ExpirationDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" HeaderText="Expiration Date" SortExpression="ExpirationDate" meta:resourceKey="lblExpirationDate" ReadOnly="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="AccountName" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="AccountName" ReadOnly="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="Location" meta:resourceKey="lblLocation" ReadOnly="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="BillTo" HeaderText="Bill To" SortExpression="BillTo" meta:resourceKey="lblBillTo" ReadOnly="true" />
                                        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="ShowEquipment" HeaderText="Equipment" Text="Show" ControlStyle-ForeColor="#822402" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="BatchNum" SortExpression="BatchNum" Visible="false" />
                                    </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
```

I am using this to try to reference that div

```
Dim divElement As HtmlGenericControl = CType(gvRenewals.FindControl("div" & agreement), HtmlGenericControl)
```

"agreement" is a variable that holds the value of the id "div<%# Eval("Agreement") %>".
"gvRenewals" is a gridview that houses the div in question

I have also tried:

```
Dim divElement As HtmlGenericControl = CType(gvRenewals.FindControl("div" & "<%=" & agreement.ToString & "%>"), HtmlGenericControl)
```

When I execute my project I receive a null reference exception on "divElement" saying "divElement was nothing" and I am at a loss as to why.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In what method are you trying to reference it? Is the page already loaded, such as on a button click or something?

Comment: @MichaelFoster, I am trying to reference it in RowCommand event for the gridview shown within the div above.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, you using a binding expression for the id, and that's probably not going to work.

I guess the REAL question is why do you want to assign a "id" at runtime? I don't see the need for this road. Without the id defined at runtime, then the code behind page class can't generate valid references in code.

And to use .findcontrol(), then you require a runat="server".

And if you do that then yo will get a compile error! (as I pointed out, resolving occurs at compile time for using .find control).

So, findcontrol requires a runat=server tag.

Since you gv has a hard coded name, then I see VERY little reason why the div you placing the gv inside of can't also have a "id".

So, then this:

```
<div id="mygridarea" class="childGrid"
   runat="server" 
   style="display:none;position:relative;left:25px;">
```

So, now in code behind, you can:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    mygridarea.Visible = False


End Sub
```

So, if you don't add a run-at server? Then you dealing with a html-post back, and you have to use js code to get that value (the page dom will not be send back to the server (well, it will, but without the parts that don't have runat="server".

Regardless, you not made the case why you need to assign the "id" of that div at runtime as opposed to design time, and in fact your gridview name is defined at runtime, so I don't see the advantage, or goal here anyway.

This is a bad idea. any control with runat="server" means resolution occurs at compile time, not runtime.